# my dapp works perfect on local but when i upload to server the address returns null using web3

Tags: web3js, server-side

I have a project which I've been working on and so far it works perfectly on local. But when I uploaded the project to the server it is unable to get address using web3.

```
const network = await web3.eth.net.getNetworkType();
console.log(network)
```

This returns ropsten so I know its connected to the correct network too. 
Have anyone faced similar issues?

```
const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
```

This line of code returns the address on local but returns nothing on server.

Comment: Local using ganache ? Or geth?

Comment: How do you connect to Ropsten in your server? Are you using Infura? Infura doesn't provide wallets API. You have to use Infura together with a wallet provider.

Comment: local also on ropsten

Comment: i am using hdwallerprovider